# Yii framework: Multi Language Support

Tags: yii, multilingual

I am developing a web site using yii framework which need to be supported in many (may be 3)
languages. 
I have problem with translating error messages that Yii framework returns.

For example how do i translate following error message which is returned by Yii framework when user does not provide correct data to log in.

Thanks in advance for any help

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii translates the error message like this,

```
Yii::t('yii','{attribute} cannot be blank.');
```

So you'd have to create a corresponding message catalogue named 'yii' and update your translations there, for more details see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/18/how-to-customize-yii-core-messages/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n